# SwiftUI display different images/text on toggle/true or false

Tags: ios, swift, button, swiftui

I'm trying to create a button that displays a different images/text depending on the current state of a task.

I've found the following doesn't work:

```swift
Button {
    taskViewModel.completeTask(id: task.id)
} label: {
    if task.taskCompleted {
        Image(systemName: "square")
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    } else {
        Image(systemName: "checkmark.square")
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}
```

But this does work:

```swift
if task.taskCompleted {
    Button {
        taskViewModel.completeTask(id: task.id)
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "checkmark.square")
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
} else {
    Button {
        taskViewModel.completeTask(id: task.id)
    } label: {
        Image(systemName: "square")
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}
```

The code that doesn't work is far cleaner!. Surely there is a better way to do this than what I've done here?

The full code that isn't working is:

```
    func TasksView(completed: Bool)->some View {
        
        LazyVStack(spacing: 20) {
            if let tasks = taskViewModel.filteredTasks{
                if tasks.isEmpty{
                    Text("No Tasks Today")
                        .offset(y: 100)
                }else{
                    ForEach(tasks){ task in
                        if completed && task.taskCompleted || !task.taskCompleted {
                            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 20) {
                                VStack(spacing: 12) {
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(taskViewModel.isCurrentHour(date: task.taskDate) ? .black : .clear)
                                        .frame(width: 13, height: 13)
                                        .background(
                                            Circle()
                                                .stroke(.black, lineWidth: 2)
                                                .padding(-4)
                                        )
                                        .scaleEffect(taskViewModel.isCurrentHour(date: task.taskDate) ? 1.2 : 0.8)
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(.black)
                                        .frame(width: 3)
                                }
                                
                                VStack {
                                    HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                                        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                                            Text(task.taskTitle)
                                                .font(.title2.bold())
                                            Text(task.taskDescription)
                                                .font(.callout)
                                                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
                                        }
                                        .headerLeading()
                                        
                                        Text(task.taskDate.formatted(date: .omitted, time: .shortened))
                                    }
                                    
                                    HStack(spacing: 8) {
                                        if taskViewModel.isCurrentHour(date: task.taskDate) {
                                        
                                            HStack(spacing: 5) {
                                                ForEach(1...3, id: \.self) { user in
                                                    Image(systemName: "person")
                                                        .resizable()
                                                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                                }
                                            }
                                            .headerLeading()
                                        }
                                        

                                            Button{
                                                taskViewModel.completeTask(id: task.id)
                                            } label: {
                                                Image(systemName: task.taskCompleted ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
                                                    .foregroundStyle(.black)
                                                    .padding(10)
                                                    .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
                                            }
                                        
                                        Button{
                                            taskViewModel.deleteTask(id: task.id)
                                        } label: {
                                            Image(systemName: "bin.xmark")
                                                .foregroundStyle(.black)
                                                .padding(10)
                                                .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))

                                        }
                                        
                                    }
                                    .padding(.top)
                                    .headerTrailing()
                                    
                                    
                                }
                                .padding(taskViewModel.isCurrentHour(date: task.taskDate) ? 15 : 0)
                                .padding(.bottom, taskViewModel.isCurrentHour(date: task.taskDate) ? 0 : 10)
                                .headerLeading()
                                .background(
                                    Color(.black)
                                        .cornerRadius(20)
                                        .opacity(taskViewModel.isCurrentHour(date: task.taskDate) ? 1 : 0)
                                )
                                .foregroundColor(taskViewModel.isCurrentHour(date: task.taskDate) ? .white : .black)
                            }.headerLeading()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                ProgressView()
                    .offset(y: 100)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .padding(.top)
        .onChange(of: taskViewModel.currentDay) { newDate in
            taskViewModel.filterTodaysTasks()
        }
    }
```

When I try to run this the following error is thrown by Xcode:

`The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions`

Comment: Is there any way you can describe your first example other than "it doesn't work"? That might offer clues as to what's going on. If possible, I'd also suggest sharing the `completeTask` method of your view model as well as the definition of `Task`.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. More specifically, you need to include your `taskViewModel` declaration on the `View` and the relevant VM code as well.

Comment: Thanks for including more information. You have got a lot of conditional code in your view construction, which can start the compilation time ramping up. As the error says, refactoring out some components – either into other functions returning `some View`, or as their own `struct`s – will usually help. It’ll probably make that whole view structure a little easier to read, too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of more details, generally the best way to adjust your view in the result of an object's property is to make the smallest adjustment necessary. In this case, you can limit the change to the `systemName` of the image:

```swift
Button {
    taskViewModel.completeTask(id: task.id)
} label: {
    Image(systemName: task.taskCompleted ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
        .foregroundStyle(.black)
        .padding(10)
        .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
}
```

What is more likely happening is that `task` isn't signalling its change to the SwiftUI rendering system, so after `completeTask` has run there's no indication that the view needs to be re-evaluated.

Comment: I also tried adding the comparison, against the Image. But this still throws the same error as trying to add an if/else in the "label" section

Comment: Thank you @ScottM the issue was due to the amount of nested conditionals :-/

Answer (score 0):

To SwiftUI, the identity of the button hasn't changed in the first example. You could fix this by adding an explicit `.id(…)`. For example:

```
Button {
    taskViewModel.completeTask(id: task.id)
} label: {
    if task.taskCompleted {
        Image(systemName: "square")
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    } else {
        Image(systemName: "checkmark.square")
            .foregroundStyle(.black)
            .padding(10)
            .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}.id("\(task.id)-\(task.completed)")
```

As soon as the task's `completed` changes, and SwiftUI is re-evaluating the UI, it will detect that the button has a different ID and will then re-render it with your new image.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better and a cleaner way to do it, based on the state of the task completed.

```
Button {
    taskViewModel.completeTask(id: task.id)
} label: {
    Image(systemName: task.taskCompleted ? "checkmark.square" : "square") // Change image based on state of the task completed
        .foregroundStyle(.black)
        .padding(10)
        .background(Color(.white), in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
}
```